# What is the verb for the action of ensuring things occur in the correct order?

Tags: verbs

In context it would be:

> 1. The marshall is responsible for **verb** the atheletes into the stadium in lane order.
> 2. The MC is responsible for **verb** the guess speakers to present in the scheduled order.
> 3. The receptionist **verb** the clients into the lawyers consulting room in the order of first in first served.

My original guess was ***marshall(ing/s)*** but that doesn't seem quite right to me but it seemed slightly better than ***arrange*** or ***order*** so I would appreciate your thought(s).

Comment: "Queueing" comes to mind for the first two, while "ushers" -a different word for a different action - seems to fit the last.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Rob_Ster.  The important need is about the "correct order".  My understanding of both queuing and ushering is that order is not necessary.

Comment: This is a problem. Your sentences *specify* that the action of the verb results in an order, so a verb that specifies ordering would be redundant. A number of synonyms suggest themselves, but since you've rejected 'to queue' (transitive), which means 'to arrange in order', it's hard to guess what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @JEL.  I agree it is hard to guess and I'm glad you took the time to consider the question.  I can assure that if I knew what the word was that I was looking for I would have asked a better question.

Comment: "Sequence" is probably the best word for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think perhaps 'to regulate' would answer:

> **2.** *trans.*
>   **a.** To control, modify, or adjust with reference to some principle, standard, or norm; to alter in response to a situation, set of circumstances, etc.

["regulate, v.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161422?rskey=qhuFbo&result=2&isAdvanced=false (accessed February 11, 2016).]

Thus, your examples might be these:

> 1. The marshall is responsible for **regulating** the entrance of the atheletes into the stadium *according to their numerical lanes of competition*.
> 2. The MC is responsible for **regulating** the appearance of the guest speakers *according to the scheduled times of their presentations*.
> 3. The receptionist **regulates** the entry of clients into the lawyer's consulting room *on the principle of 'first come, first served'*.

In each of 1-3, the "principal, standard, or norm" employed for regulation is emphasized with italics.

Answer (score 0):

JEL mentions that you're being redundant with your phrasing, but I'm assuming it's to help impart the purpose of the sentence until you have the correct word.

"Collating" comes to mind, such as when printing papers.

> Collate: to collect and combine (texts, information, or sets of figures) in proper order

Comment: yes your assumption is correct and collate was an interesting suggestion that pointed me towards a little known defintion (by me at least) of the word range being "place or arrange in a row or rows or in a specified manner."  This seems correct but quite uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

First word which comes to my mind after reading your question is 'Sort' or 'Sorting'.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential part? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.